# Does $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ (or $SL_n(\mathbb{C})$ ) have significance as an algebraic set?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, lie-groups

The determinant of a matrix is a polynomial in its entries, and the matrices in $SL_n(\mathbb{F})$, when written out as points in $\mathbb{F}^{n^2}$, are precisely the zero set of (said polynomial $-1$), which is an algebraic subset of $\mathbb{F}^{n^2}$.

Is there any meaningful algebro - geometric consequence of this?

Comment: What sort of answer do you seek? What is your background? Have you read much about [algebraic groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_group#Definitions)?

Comment: I’ve had courses on Linear Algebra and Group Theory, and I’ve read some amount of comm algebra and classical algebraic geometry by myself. As for what answer I seek, I’m not really sure, guess I’m sort of trying to find interesting connections to algebraic geometry. 

I glanced at the page you linked, and is it fair to say that these are the algebraic analogues of Lie groups? After all, this idea did strike me during an introductory talk on Lie groups and Lie algebras.

Comment: The entire field of *geometric representation theory* is probably what you are looking for.